# Is possible to call an overridden method from another plugin?

Tags: java, plugins

I'm coding two plugins for a program, one of this plugin is a "library plugin" and contains a lot of classes used by the other plugins, the other is one of the plugin based on this library. All works well except one thing.
In my library plugin I wrote a socket class sintetized to this:

```
public class MServerSocket {
    public void initServer(int port) {
        //Code to receive message from client
        execute(input, clientOutput);
    }

    public void execute(String input, DataOutputStream clientOutput) {
        System.out.println(input);
        send(clientOutput, input);
    }

    public void send(DataOutputStream clientOutput, String output) {
        //Code to send message to client
    }
}
```

In the other plugin I extend this class and override the execute method to do something, like this:

```
public class MySocketServer extends MServerSocket {
    @Override
    public void execute(String input, DataOutputStream clientOutput) {
        //Do something
        MServerSocket.send(clientOutput, input)
    }
}
```

Now my second plugin should override my library plugin class but it doesn't.
In the second plugin I call it in the main like this:

```
public class Main {
    public void onEnable() { //method called to load plugin
        private static MServerSocket socket = new MServerSocket();
        socket.initServer(12980);
    }
}
```

When I send a socket message to my socket it is printed to the console as said in the library execute method.

So here I am, can someone give me an answer and possibly a solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: "But it doesn't" - please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, I hope now I'm more clear

Comment: I'm not even sure how your code compiles at the moment, let alone runs. e.g. why are you declaring a private variable within a method?

Comment: No it's not private, to simplify i copied some parts of the code and this "private static MServerSocket socket = new MServerSocket(); " was not in the function

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently constructs a `MServerSocket` object but if you want the behaviour of your `MySocketServer` to be executed, you need to construct one of those.

You should also change (at a minimum):

`MServerSocket.send(clientOutput, input)`

...to

`super.send(clientOutput, input)`

...as that's the proper way to delegate to a method from the parent class.